# when I use bootstrap popover on fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, popover

I added on fullcalendar a bootstrap popover, but each event on the calendar must be two clicks, popover appear.   here is the code. 
I tried to remove the body of the click does not work.
https://jsfiddle.net/pLsraez0/6/

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
        element.popover({
            title: function () {
                return "<B>" + event.subject + "</B>";
            },
            placement:'auto',
            html:true,
            trigger : 'click',
            animation : 'false',
            content: function () {
                return "<div>" +
                        "计划开始时间：" + event.start.format() +
                    "<br />计划结束时间：" + event.end.format() +
                    "<br />需求提交人：" + event.chargeusername +
                    "<br />需求PM：" + event.pmusername +
                    "<br />需求类型：" + event.projecttype +
                    "<br />预计工作量：" + event.workload +
                    "<br />需求级别：" + event.projectlevel +
                    "<br /><input type='hidden' value='" + event.id + "' />" +
                    "</div>" +
                "<div style='text-align: right;margin-top: 10px;'>" +
                "<button type='button' onclick='designProj(event);' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>指派</button>" +
                "<button style='margin-left: 8px;' onclick='editProj(event);' type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-xs'>编辑</button>" +
                "<button style='margin-left: 8px;' onclick='delProj(event);' type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-xs'>删除</button>" +
                "</div>";
            },
            container:'body'
        }).popover('show');
        $('body').on('click', function (e) {
            if (!element.is(e.target) && element.has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0)
                element.popover('hide');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$(element)`. It work fine for me.
https://jsfiddle.net/PJ1501/pLsraez0/4/

Comment: When I click elsewhere pages, popover to disappear，So I added the following code, and then there have been problems need to click twice。                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         `$('body').on('click', function (e) {
            if (!element.is(e.target) && element.has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0)
                element.popover('hide');
        });`

Comment: so you need use `focus` in trigger instead of `click` and have to add attributes `role="button" tabindex="0"` 
in case user click in calendar, add ` $(element).blur();` in your ` $('body').on('click',function(e){ })` function.
https://jsfiddle.net/pLsraez0/10/
read more at: [Dismiss on next click](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dismiss-on-next-click)